# In OOP, what is the best practice in regards to using "this" inside a class?

Tags: java, oop, coding-style

Something I've always wondered; in a class where you can reference a member by either using 'this.[NAME]' or simply [NAME], which is preferred?

For example in Java:

```
public class foo {
    public int bars = 0;
    private void incrementBars(){
        bars++;
    }
}
```

and

```
public class foo {
    public int bars = 0;
    private void incrementBars(){
        this.bars++;
    }
}
```

'seem' to have the same effect.

In cases where I instantiate multiple instances of class foo, I'd, so far, do something like:

```
for (foo f : listOfFoos){
    f.incrementBars();
}
```

and it seems to still work.

Is it technically ambiguous, and if so is there a preferred way?

Comment: Note that both approaches don't just *seem* to have the same effect -- they actually do.  `this.` is implied when accessing instance members, and the compiled bytecode will be identical for either syntax.

Comment: ""this. is implied" ... and the compiled bytecode will be identical for either syntax" - Oooooooh :)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

use [`this`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) in the case of [`variable shadowing`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html).

```
 class MyClass{
        int i;//1
        public void myMethod(){
            i = 10;//referring to 1    
        }

        public void myMethod(int i){//2
            i = 10;//referring to 2
            this.i = 10 //refering to 1    
        }    
    }
```

also sometime [`this`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) will make code more readable due to our English mindset

Comment: Personally I find `this.` *always* more readable. Imo it introduces consistency. You can be sure that that variable, regardless of the context, is a member of the object.

Comment: @Felix  Yes,it will simulate english's `this` so it would make it simpler

Comment: I don't think @Felix meant that it made more semantic sense, but rather that it makes the variable visually stand out and reduces the cognitive load: while you have more text to read, it gives you direct information on the variable. I am myself a bit torn between using and not using "this" systematically: whenever I'm in an IDE or editor with decent language support, it appears clearly overkill. But whenever you revert to reading code in black-on-white text, it helps tremendously. It's just a habit.

Answer (score 6):

There's no ambiguity. If there were, you'd **have** to use `this`.

Some people recommend `this` for clarity. Others recommend against it when it's not required, as it introduces "noise". Some modern IDEs or editors may be able to use syntax highlighting to color (for instance) arguments differently from fields for clarity.

Personally I avoid `this` when I can and use [@unholysampler's underscore convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4641202/161457). Agree on something with your coworkers and put it in your coding standards.

Answer (score 3):

You use `this` to ensure and communicate that you are dealing with a *field*.

It allows you to write a setter like

```
public void setX(int x) {
  this.x = x;
}
```

which is very succint.

Answer (score 2):

The only time you need `this.` is when the current scope also has a variable of the same name. I prefer to use the convention of `_variable` for all class variables. This way I never have to use `this.` and never accidentally touch a class variable thinking it was a locally scoped variable.

Answer (score 1):

In your question the first two samples have exactly the same thing. The only where `this` is mandatory is when an attribute is shadowed by a local variable:

```
public class Test {
    private int a;

    public void noShadow() {
        System.out.println(a); // attribute
    }

    public void shadow(int a) {
        System.out.println(a); // parameter
        System.out.println(this.a); // attribute
    }
}
```

Now I don't think there is an absolute best practice, especially as modern IDEs provide advanced syntax highlighting. Some like to prefix the attribute with something like `_`, `m_`, etc. and not use `this`. Some prefer to make the use of `this` mandatory and do not add any naming rules on attributes. What you are going to do is vastly depending on the existing code or existing coding standards. I nothing exists ensure that the coding standards will be the same for all people working on the project.

Answer (score 0):

```
class Test
{
  private int value;

  public Test(int value)
  {
     // This is wrong
     // value = value

     // This is right
     this.value = value;
  }
}
```

Use "this" to access member variables when they have been hidden by a local variable.
Since "this" is just a reference to the current object, ou can do this:

```
doSomething(this);
```

These are essentially the only ways you will ever need to use this.

Comment: In regards to the last point you make, by your logic, using `private` is redundant in pretty much every possible use case, since any declaration would be "correct" without it -- and yet you have used it in the `value` field declaration.  I'm not saying I recommend using `this.` in method invocation context, I'm just pointing out that you contradict your own reasoning.

Comment: using this.method() instead of method() is redundant because it compiles to the same bytecode/machine code, any reason to do this is purely stylistic.

Comment: However, marking a variable as private vs protected hides the variable from inherited classes, which is in many cases necessary.

Answer (score 0):

It is technically ambiguous except in the case of where you have variable shadowing (which Jigar pointed out in his answer).

Most often if you working in an editor / IDE that is very aware of your class structure syntax highlighting will make it obvious as to whether or not a variable is field in the object or just a variable defined in a method.  However, in more pure text editors (vim, for instance)the syntax highlighting doesn't make this clear.

With that said, I prefer using this.field to refer to all fields that belong in the object if only because I know that every now and then I'll be reading code outside of my normal IDEs.  It is marginally more verbose, but that's a tradeoff I don't mind.